# Array aggregation on self-defined types?

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vivado

I'm trying to implement an FSM with a RAM behavior. There are multiple addresses of this ram that should be initialized while describing this FSM. So, I'm using the array aggregation technique to initialize the first 20 addresses of the *ram_block*. However, I'm getting a *bad syntax* error on each line the aggregation has occurred or the partial section of the ram_block(i) has initialized. Any helps would be appreciated.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity RegisterController is
    port(
        r1_p: inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        r2_p: inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        write_p: in std_logic;
        enable_p: in std_logic;
        clk_p: in std_logic;
        ram_rw: in std_logic;                       -- 0 => Read from ram | 1 => Write to the ram
        reset_p: in std_logic
    );
end RegisterController;

architecture RTL of RegisterController is
    -- Create the ram word
    subtype ram_word is std_logic_vector(66 downto 0);

    -- Create the ram block of 32 ram_words
    type ram_block is array (31 downto 0) of ram_word;

    -- Address to read from the ram
    signal R_ADDR_S: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "00000";

begin
    RAM_LOAD: process(clk)
    begin 
        -- We're gonna load the 32 words of this ram with clock first
        -- Outputs are being updated in the runtime :D
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(ram_rw = '1') then
                -- STATE 0 DESCRIPTION
                ram_block(0) <= ("000", std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)), std_logic_vector(to_unsgined(0, 32)));
                ram_block(1) <= ("000", std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)), std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)));
                ram_block(2) <= ("001", std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)), std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)));
                ram_block(3) <= ("001", std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)), std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 32)));

                -- STATE 1 DESCRIPTION
                ram_block(4) <= (66 downto 64) => "001";
                ram_block(5) <= (66 downto 64) => "001";
                ram_block(6) <= ("001", r2_p, r1_p);
                ram_block(7) <= (66 downto 64) => "010";

                -- STATE 2 DESCRIPTION
                ram_block(8) <= (66 downto 64) => "010";
                ram_block(9) <= (66 downto 64) => "010";
                ram_block(10) <= (66 downto 64) => "011";
                ram_block(11) <= (66 downto 64) => "011";

                -- STATE 3 DESCRIPTION
                ram_block(12) <= (66 downto 64) => "011";
                ram_block(13) <= (66 downto 64) => "011";
                ram_block(14) <= (66 downto 64) => "100";
                ram_block(15) <= (66 downto 64) => "100";

                -- STATE 4 DESCRIPTION
                ram_block(16) <= (66 downto 64) => "100";
                ram_block(17) <= (66 downto 64) => "100";
                ram_block(18) <= (66 downto 64) => "001";
                ram_block(19) <= (66 downto 64) => "001";
                ram_block(31 downto 20) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 67));
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    START_FSM: process(clk)
        -- TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE THE READ VALUE FROM THE RAM BLOCK
        variable temp_read_ram: std_logic_vector(66 downto 0);
        variable temp_read_ram2: std_logic_vector(66 downto 0);
        -- R3 Declaration as a variable 
        variable R3_V: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    begin 
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(ram_rw = '0') then
                -- START READING THE RAM FROM ADDRESS 0
                temp_read_ram := ram_block(to_integer(unsigned(R_ADDR_S)));
                R_ADDR_S(4 downto 2) <= temp_read_ram(66 downto 64);
                R_ADDR_S(1 downto 0) <= (enable_p, write_p);

                -- UPDATE THE OUTPUTS
                if(R_ADDR_S = "00110") then
                    -- READ THE PREVIOUS VALUE IN THAT ADDRESS
                    temp_read_ram2 <= ram_block(R_ADDR_S);
                    -- UPDATE THE OUTPUT VALUES INSIDE RAM
                    ram_block(R_ADDR_S) <= (temp_read_ram2(66 downto 64), r2_p, r1_p);
                    -- NO NEED TO UPDATE r2_p and r1_p
                elsif(R_ADDR_S = "00111") then
                    -- PUT THE CURRENT VALUE OF R1 TO THE R3
                    temp_read_ram2 <= ram_block(R_ADDR_S);
                    -- SAVE R1 TO THE R3_V
                    R3_V := temp_read_ram2(31 downto 0);

                elsif(R_ADDR_S = "01110" or R_ADDR_S = "01111") then
                    -- READ THE PREVIOUS VALIE IN THOSE ADDRESSES
                    temp_read_ram2 <= ram_block(R_ADDR_S);
                    -- UPDATE THE OUTPUT VALUE OF R2 INSIDE RAM
                    ram_block(R_ADDR_S) <= (temp_read_ram2(66 downto 64), R3_V, temp_read_ram2(31 downto 0)); 
                    -- UPDATE THE OUTPUT VALUE OF r2_p
                    r2_p <= R3_V;
               else
               else
                    -- NO CHANGE
                    ram_block(R_ADDR_S) <= ram_block(R_ADDR_S);
               end if;
           end if;
       end if;
   end process;       
end RTL;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's not one, but many syntax errors in your code.

First off, `ram_block` is a *type*, not a signal. So why are you assigning values to it? You need to declare a signal first. I.e.

```
-- Create the ram block of 32 ram_words
type ram_block_type is array (31 downto 0) of ram_word;
signal ram_block : ram_block_type := (others => (others => '0'));
```

^ what I also include here, is initialization of the signal. Same can be done for:

```
signal R_ADDR_S: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

In the process, you are assigning values to many locations in the RAM at the same time! That is not RAM-like. A random access memory usually only has 1 or 2 ports, accessing 1 resp. 2 elements at a time. You are designing generic distributed memory, so imho should not call it RAM.

Assigning to part of the array has a specific syntax. You can either assign the whole matrix in one go (this is VHDL-2008 by the way):

```
ram_block <= (4 => (66 downto 64 => "001", others => '0'), others => '0');
```

Note: you need to assign all values here, hence the `others` statement.
Second option, assign one sub-array

```
ram_block(4) <= (66 downto 64 => "001", others => '0');
```

Finally, and probably what you want, assign a specific sub-set of a sub-array:

```
ram_block(4)(66 downto 64) <= "001";
```

But in this case, you want to initialize the array, as else unassigned `std_logic`'s will have the default value 'U'.

Then:

```
ram_block(31 downto 20) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 67));
```

This will not work. You're assigning an array structure to an array-of-arrays.

Variable `R3_V` is assigned in one situation, but not used directly: It is used a different clock cycle. In that case do not use a variable: that is bad coding style. It should be a signal.

And **you must remember that signals assigned in a clocked process will not have access to their new value until the next delta cycle**. Thus the assignment of signal `R_ADDR_S(4 downto 2) <= temp_read_ram(66 downto 64);` will not be available for the following if-statements!

Other things:

- `clk` should probably be `clk_p`
- `to_unsgined` -> `to_unsigned`
- in line 79 you use the correct `ram_block(to_integer(unsigned(R_ADDR_S)))`, but later (line 86) you do it wrong `ram_block(R_ADDR_S)`
- in line 79 you also correctly assign a variable using `:=`, but later (line 86 again) you use the incorrect `<=`.
- there's a double `else` at the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation.

Comment: It is worth saying that I was curious about my style of coding in VHDL. While coding in a new programming language, I'm always looking for the conventions in that specific community. I'm aware of this point that you are not here to review my code. I was just looking for improvements. Thanks anyway, Cheers. :)

Comment: There are two processes that assign to `ram_block`, noting that process `RAM_LOAD` writes to all it's elements and process `START_FSM` can write to any of the elements of `ram_block`.  IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1 *longest static prefix*, 14.7 Execution of a model, 14.7.2 Drivers, ... There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment ...  denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement.

Comment: @user1155120 Voting down kills more dreams than syntax error will :)

Comment: The question and answer are reminiscent of the [blind men and an elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." "any helps" is non-specific the non-authoritative answer not exhaustive.

Comment: @user1155120 It is important to mention the question title again which is the exact error I was getting from the Vivado. This simply means that I've read the errors but those described above by dear JHBonarius are the ones that I wasn't aware of. The main problem was on the aggregation and the true syntax in array aggregating the self-defined types. :)